# Finding the binary containing a function

Tags: python, gdb

I'm trying to use python extension to figure out if a given frame is executed from the same binary a given symbol comes from. Specifically:

I'm looking at a Ruby stack trace and would like to automatically tell whether a frame comes from ruby/libruby, or a different binary. The main criteria for this is: does the `pc` of the frame belong to the same `soname` as the symbol `ruby_exec_node`.

This is doable in gdb itself:

```
#69 0x00007fe00444e783 in invoke_block (...) at vm.c:921
921 in vm.c
(gdb) info symbol 0x00007fe00444e783
invoke_block.isra + 387 in section .text of /host/ruby-2.3.3
(gdb) info symbol ruby_exec_node
ruby_exec_node in section .text of /host/ruby-2.3.3
```

You can see that both symbols come from `/host/ruby-2.3.3`.

From the docs, it looks like python should be able to access this via `gdb.solib_name`, but I can't get this out:

```
ruby_exec_node = gdb.lookup_global_symbol('ruby_exec_node')
ruby_solib = gdb.solib_name(ruby_exec_node.value().address)
print(ruby_solib)
```

gives me `None`. How else can I get this information from the symbol?

The second part is getting the same information out of a `pc` address. I can do the following to get the address:

```
gdb.selected_frame().pc()
```

But how do I find a symbol it corresponds to, similar to `info symbol ...`?

Answer (score 0):

Solutions to those 2 problems are:

Going from a symbol to an object file (not necessarily the path - `objfile` can be compared):

```
ruby_exec_node = gdb.lookup_global_symbol('ruby_exec_node')
ruby_file = ruby_exec_node.symtab.objfile
```

And looking up the `objfile` of the current frame (`current`):

```
sal = current.find_sal()
if not sal.symtab:
    # skip frame - doesn't contain symtab

if sal.symtab.objfile == ruby_file:
    # this frame executes code from the ruby binary
```